# Will Iodine Tablets Ruin My CamelBak?

Tags: backpacking, water-purification, hydration-bladders

In the past, I have gone backpacking with some fairly expensive, heavy water purification tools. But the more I read about water safety in California's Sierras ([here](http://www.rei.com/learn/expert-advice/water-researcher-QA.html) and [here](http://www.cdc.gov/healthywater/drinking/travel/backcountry_water_treatment.html)), the less I think these high-tech solutions are necessary.

**Can I just drop some iodine tablets into my CamelBak?**

Will the tablets:

1. react with the plastic bladder and destroy it?
2. stain the plastic bladder dark purple?
3. make the CamelBak taste like iodine permanently?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. nope
2. yep (actually, yellow, not purple, thanks Clare)
3. Not in my experience, but I use clarifiers which remove the flavor in the water.

Also to clarify from comments, we did this for *years* before we started carrying a filter and  it never damaged our containers.  The plastic probably gets more damage from the sunlight caught during hiking than from the iodine.

Comment: 2.)  Ours is yellowed, and not dark purple, but yep-- it's stained for good.  I should note, though, that it's just around the edges that it's really noticeable.  No cracks or bad taste or smell, just some yellowing.

Comment: Ah! Thank you. I was unable to tell from Russell's answer if this was from personal experience or if someone was just stating what they *thought* would be true. The first-hand experience is key. Thanks to both of you for the help.